# Syntax for crossed random effects with random slopes nlme

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I'm creating a number of models with a crossed random effects structure that allows for heteroscedasticity. In my analysis I have measurements of nest elevation (Z), each associated with a parent (MaleID) and a study area (Area). Males move between different study areas, so each level of MaleID can be associated with multiple levels of Area.

Additionally, the elevation measurements have been collected using a couple of different methods (Method) that will vary in their precision. Therefore, I wanted to build a heteroscedastic model that takes into account this variation in measurement error. As I understand it, this can only be done in nlme.

Using these resources (https://goo.gl/sK7nGf and http://goo.gl/EgEcje) I built this model with nlme:

```
lme(Z ~ 1, data = ELEV, 
    random = list(const = pdBlocked(list(pdIdent(~Area - 1), pdIdent(~MaleID - 1)))), 
    weights = varIdent(form = ~1|Method))
```

Now, as a next step, I want to include a fixed effect Year and add a term for random slopes of Year across levels of MaleID (in addition to random intercepts). I know in nlme this would normally be coded:

```
random = ~1 + Year|MaleID
```

But I can't work out how this can be done with my crossed random effects structure.

1. Could anybody tell me how random slopes might be added in to my above example?
2. Am I correct in assuming that this type of model can only be built using nlme or is there a possible work around for heteroscedastic models in lme4 that I've missed?

As my data often includes a crossed random effects structure using lme4 would make things heaps easier. Thank you!

I've included a dput() output of a subset of my data below. The whole dataset is a few thousand records long, but the basic structure of this subset is the same. Please note that MaleID is treated as a factor.

```
structure(list(Year = c(1995L, 1995L, 1995L, 1995L, 1995L, 1995L, 
1995L, 1996L, 1996L, 1996L, 1996L, 1996L, 1996L, 1996L, 1996L, 
1996L, 1996L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 
2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 
2001L, 2001L, 2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 
2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2004L, 2004L, 
2004L, 2004L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2006L, 1996L, 1996L, 
1996L, 1996L, 2011L, 1995L, 1995L, 2001L, 2001L, 1996L, 1996L, 
1996L, 1996L, 2003L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2003L, 1996L, 1996L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2009L, 2009L, 1996L, 2001L, 2004L, 1995L, 1995L, 
1995L, 1996L, 2004L, 2012L, 2012L, 1995L, 2002L, 2002L, 2004L, 
2004L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 1995L, 2004L, 
1996L, 1996L, 2000L, 2003L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 
1996L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 1996L, 1996L, 1996L, 1996L, 1996L, 
1996L, 1996L, 2001L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2012L, 2012L, 2000L, 
2000L, 2000L, 2001L, 2009L, 2004L, 2004L, 2005L, 2005L, 2006L, 
2008L, 1996L, 2003L, 2003L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2009L, 2009L, 
2009L, 1995L, 1996L, 2000L, 2000L, 2005L, 2008L, 2010L, 1996L, 
2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 1996L, 1996L, 1996L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2011L, 1995L, 2012L, 2012L, 1995L, 2000L, 2004L, 2009L, 
2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2009L, 2013L, 
2013L, 2013L, 1996L, 2003L, 2004L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 
1995L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2010L, 1996L, 2003L, 2007L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2005L, 2005L, 2012L, 2012L, 
2012L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 1996L, 2000L, 2003L, 2003L, 2004L, 
2006L, 2006L, 2009L, 1995L, 2008L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 1995L, 
1995L, 2000L, 2004L, 2006L, 2009L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2002L, 
2002L, 2004L, 2006L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2008L, 2008L, 1996L, 
2002L, 2006L, 2011L, 2011L, 1996L, 2001L, 1995L, 2001L, 2008L, 
2010L, 1995L, 1995L, 1995L, 1995L, 2001L, 2008L, 1996L, 2003L, 
2013L, 1995L, 1995L, 1995L, 2001L, 2001L, 2003L, 2003L, 2004L, 
2004L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2006L, 2009L, 2009L, 1995L, 1995L, 
1996L, 1996L, 1996L, 2003L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2009L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2007L, 2008L, 
2008L, 1995L, 1995L, 1995L, 1995L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 
2010L, 1996L, 1996L, 2001L, 2002L, 2004L, 2003L, 2004L, 1995L, 
2001L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 1996L, 1996L, 
1996L, 1996L, 2005L, 2005L, 1995L, 1995L, 1995L, 2001L, 2007L, 
2010L, 2010L, 1996L, 1996L, 2009L, 1995L, 2005L, 1995L, 1995L, 
1995L, 1995L, 1995L, 1996L, 1996L, 2007L, 2007L, 2006L, 2010L, 
1995L, 1995L, 1995L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2001L, 2009L, 
2008L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 1996L, 1996L, 1996L, 2005L, 2006L, 
2012L, 2014L, 1995L, 2012L, 2012L, 1995L, 1995L, 1996L, 1995L, 
1995L, 1995L, 2003L, 2007L, 1995L, 1995L, 1996L, 2003L, 2007L, 
2010L, 2010L, 1996L, 2009L, 2011L, 1996L, 2014L, 1995L, 1995L, 
2007L, 2013L, 2013L, 1996L, 1996L, 2005L, 2005L, 2007L, 2013L, 
2002L, 2002L, 2003L, 2008L, 1995L, 1995L, 1995L, 2008L, 2002L, 
2004L, 2005L, 2014L, 1996L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2005L, 2008L, 
2010L, 1995L, 1995L, 1995L, 2005L, 2004L, 2002L, 2006L, 1995L, 
2008L, 1996L, 2001L, 2014L, 2014L, 2009L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 
1995L, 2013L, 1995L, 2006L, 2012L, 1995L, 1995L, 1995L, 1995L, 
2010L, 2007L, 2010L), Z = c(164, 136, 156, 147, 136, 141, 135, 
179, 167, 193, 153, 147, 152, 156, 140, 167, 143, 160, 175, 250, 
111, 163, 163, 171, 148, 150, 175, 197, 147, 146, 159, 147, 207, 
161, 168, 250, 250, 177, 168, 153, 118, 169, 162, 202, 168, 201, 
116, 180, 220, 196, 164, 184, 180, 174, 146, 198, 151, 148, 150, 
152, 156, 166, 168, 168, 155, 131, 143, 151, 161, 137, 156, 231, 
179, 172, 186, 236, 173, 144, 205, 188, 145, 154, 148, 145, 224, 
137, 157, 161, 142, 181, 154, 158, 148, 181, 181, 250, 250, 142, 
187, 142, 146, 146, 145, 145, 158, 141, 151, 165, 114, 160, 143, 
152, 206, 141, 170, 203, 130, 149, 150, 159, 162, 170, 178, 155, 
151, 243, 163, 197, 229, 185, 250, 144, 136, 158, 174, 178, 250, 
249, 189, 241, 218, 141, 160, 147, 202, 146, 148, 155, 183, 195, 
182, 161, 150, 250, 164, 172, 137, 143, 177, 154, 180, 138, 136, 
140, 145, 195, 233, 176, 166, 145, 160, 133, 137, 140, 164, 167, 
155, 143, 135, 250, 145, 145, 146, 141, 147, 201, 176, 179, 220, 
250, 149, 140, 147, 149, 155, 146, 131, 250, 154, 250, 160, 148, 
144, 175, 155, 143, 143, 155, 139, 153, 153, 140, 132, 143, 137, 
141, 143, 159, 143, 158, 143, 134, 146, 137, 177, 204, 144, 160, 
160, 161, 141, 131, 144, 204, 182, 142, 153, 157, 154, 169, 172, 
147, 147, 177, 208, 150, 142, 144, 137, 158, 154, 250, 189, 148, 
151, 160, 168, 149, 138, 149, 155, 161, 214, 250, 136, 146, 164, 
136, 154, 167, 144, 119, 147, 170, 136, 157, 131, 138, 180, 175, 
157, 177, 192, 152, 159, 136, 137, 142, 250, 195, 176, 145, 198, 
207, 145, 149, 166, 159, 193, 227, 166, 150, 155, 150, 162, 160, 
151, 142, 149, 140, 250, 180, 144, 161, 163, 136, 142, 148, 179, 
161, 170, 165, 221, 164, 129, 160, 159, 143, 163, 138, 155, 141, 
250, 243, 141, 146, 144, 166, 157, 157, 153, 142, 135, 162, 159, 
139, 146, 151, 149, 153, 147, 149, 128, 133, 192, 223, 156, 123, 
157, 164, 142, 157, 198, 203, 180, 165, 157, 196, 165, 210, 151, 
156, 155, 143, 162, 142, 148, 172, 140, 139, 146, 138, 155, 134, 
139, 167, 162, 176, 153, 158, 156, 138, 115, 164, 199, 156, 140, 
152, 151, 136, 148, 143, 138, 152, 152, 158, 142, 169, 124, 144, 
128, 156, 133, 145, 163, 165, 158, 155, 183, 190, 250, 170, 136, 
140, 144, 168, 173, 160, 162, 165, 151, 155, 153, 156, 165, 139, 
142, 165, 145, 204, 144, 177, 157, 173, 131, 149, 149, 158, 146, 
144, 150, 174, 159, 158, 155, 150, 150, 162, 225), Method = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("DGPS", "LID"
), class = "factor"), Area = structure(c(7L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 9L, 1L, 1L, 
19L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 19L, 19L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 19L, 19L, 1L, 13L, 1L, 7L, 20L, 1L, 17L, 20L, 15L, 13L, 20L, 
19L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 1L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 19L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 19L, 7L, 8L, 
19L, 19L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 19L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 
3L, 15L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 19L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 19L, 7L, 19L, 19L, 18L, 18L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 7L, 19L, 
19L, 1L, 19L, 9L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 7L, 
1L, 19L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 9L, 19L, 
9L, 7L, 1L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 7L, 19L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 17L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 19L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 1L, 19L, 1L, 5L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 19L, 7L, 1L, 7L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 8L, 7L, 1L, 19L, 19L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 19L, 9L, 
9L, 1L, 17L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 19L, 1L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 1L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 7L, 19L, 19L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 19L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 19L, 19L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 2L, 5L, 8L, 17L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 17L, 17L, 19L, 7L, 
19L, 3L, 3L, 17L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 17L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 9L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 8L, 5L, 8L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 
8L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 17L, 19L, 
8L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 9L, 17L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
17L), .Label = c("A", "B", "Be", "BE", "Bw", "BW", "C", "D", 
"E", "F", "Fe", "FE", "Fw", "FW", "HD", "Nbk", "NBK", "Obk", 
"OBK", "TBK"), class = "factor"), MaleID = c(67, 62, 88, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 2, 69, 60, 4, 35, 68, 53, 16, 61, 79, 9, 14, 55, 80, 77, 
47, 63, 74, 56, 19, 15, 47, 74, 85, 72, 72, 9, 25, 55, 15, 63, 
18, 34, 88, 1, 64, 42, 54, 6, 68, 54, 45, 92, 37, 37, 97, 79, 
94, 95, 86, 25, 12, 12, 12, 20, 77, 10, 12, 80, 80, 44, 44, 31, 
31, 19, 82, 82, 82, 33, 9, 73, 17, 17, 83, 83, 75, 83, 19, 20, 
20, 84, 30, 34, 67, 67, 24, 9, 9, 43, 43, 83, 83, 83, 83, 74, 
74, 36, 57, 81, 82, 28, 59, 33, 5, 5, 87, 80, 25, 15, 97, 97, 
8, 84, 84, 85, 85, 85, 57, 43, 67, 17, 17, 17, 17, 83, 78, 78, 
27, 77, 15, 45, 83, 55, 95, 77, 14, 74, 74, 5, 5, 57, 95, 95, 
95, 44, 97, 43, 85, 34, 83, 83, 52, 82, 82, 74, 40, 40, 27, 95, 
15, 95, 77, 85, 39, 78, 78, 29, 27, 77, 97, 78, 78, 78, 83, 83, 
83, 78, 32, 83, 83, 83, 46, 15, 39, 97, 97, 32, 32, 13, 78, 78, 
78, 78, 67, 98, 9, 93, 97, 97, 32, 32, 32, 77, 5, 97, 97, 97, 
97, 97, 97, 39, 64, 64, 80, 67, 86, 86, 67, 9, 78, 44, 44, 44, 
80, 80, 81, 85, 77, 44, 44, 44, 44, 47, 85, 32, 74, 77, 15, 32, 
32, 32, 3, 78, 33, 78, 78, 77, 57, 85, 94, 97, 78, 11, 11, 41, 
46, 55, 67, 80, 67, 78, 8, 59, 97, 88, 88, 85, 32, 59, 59, 59, 
82, 67, 97, 86, 86, 86, 86, 34, 34, 34, 43, 95, 95, 5, 93, 33, 
33, 67, 85, 32, 65, 43, 97, 94, 94, 94, 27, 71, 71, 66, 25, 44, 
15, 15, 74, 96, 96, 84, 80, 25, 87, 74, 14, 63, 43, 57, 74, 5, 
5, 5, 32, 47, 47, 76, 43, 43, 58, 58, 91, 97, 67, 5, 5, 56, 56, 
85, 22, 74, 50, 38, 38, 38, 38, 67, 59, 78, 82, 93, 15, 26, 26, 
48, 32, 32, 93, 93, 15, 56, 86, 59, 59, 93, 23, 23, 23, 80, 82, 
85, 32, 77, 83, 83, 47, 47, 89, 30, 30, 63, 57, 42, 21, 90, 28, 
49, 86, 59, 59, 86, 59, 5, 63, 83, 7, 70, 74, 5, 5, 99, 5, 44, 
59, 59, 77, 32, 32, 86, 85, 28, 87, 87, 33, 82, 78, 56, 97, 87, 
44, 44, 44, 78, 56, 81, 32, 32, 32, 57, 86, 59, 44, 25, 59, 51, 
34, 93, 93, 81, 44, 78, 78, 23, 85, 40, 94, 93, 31, 5, 5, 5, 
85, 85, 93), const = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "1", class = "factor")), .Names = c("Year", 
"Z", "Method", "Area", "MaleID", "const"), row.names = c(1L, 
4L, 5L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 20L, 21L, 26L, 27L, 33L, 39L, 42L, 
141L, 160L, 162L, 169L, 170L, 171L, 172L, 176L, 177L, 179L, 180L, 
190L, 194L, 205L, 213L, 215L, 216L, 221L, 222L, 224L, 227L, 312L, 
318L, 320L, 321L, 323L, 324L, 325L, 329L, 334L, 349L, 498L, 540L, 
541L, 551L, 703L, 714L, 715L, 722L, 754L, 762L, 763L, 764L, 812L, 
1008L, 1009L, 1010L, 1012L, 1015L, 1017L, 1038L, 1043L, 1044L, 
1053L, 1054L, 1055L, 1056L, 1057L, 1058L, 1059L, 1060L, 1078L, 
1082L, 1099L, 1101L, 1102L, 1116L, 1117L, 1130L, 1135L, 1136L, 
1143L, 1144L, 1150L, 1151L, 1154L, 1170L, 1171L, 1180L, 1181L, 
1182L, 1183L, 1184L, 1190L, 1191L, 1192L, 1193L, 1197L, 1198L, 
1203L, 1208L, 1214L, 1216L, 1217L, 1218L, 1219L, 1220L, 1221L, 
1222L, 1223L, 1231L, 1234L, 1235L, 1236L, 1263L, 1275L, 1276L, 
1277L, 1278L, 1279L, 1283L, 1284L, 1302L, 1312L, 1313L, 1318L, 
1319L, 1329L, 1331L, 1332L, 1333L, 1340L, 1361L, 1363L, 1364L, 
1365L, 1369L, 1373L, 1395L, 1396L, 1397L, 1400L, 1401L, 1430L, 
1434L, 1435L, 1436L, 1452L, 1453L, 1454L, 1455L, 1459L, 1460L, 
1461L, 1479L, 1481L, 1482L, 1486L, 1509L, 1510L, 1511L, 1519L, 
1520L, 1522L, 1523L, 1531L, 1543L, 1571L, 1572L, 1579L, 1582L, 
1584L, 1592L, 1618L, 1619L, 1620L, 1627L, 1628L, 1629L, 1631L, 
1642L, 1650L, 1651L, 1652L, 1661L, 1664L, 1666L, 1679L, 1680L, 
1681L, 1682L, 1707L, 1723L, 1724L, 1725L, 1726L, 1727L, 1734L, 
1745L, 1748L, 1756L, 1757L, 1758L, 1759L, 1760L, 1771L, 1772L, 
1797L, 1798L, 1799L, 1807L, 1808L, 1809L, 1812L, 1813L, 1815L, 
1817L, 1818L, 1822L, 1823L, 1826L, 1833L, 1841L, 1845L, 1846L, 
1847L, 1855L, 1856L, 1861L, 1863L, 1869L, 1872L, 1874L, 1875L, 
1876L, 1898L, 1899L, 1900L, 1905L, 1906L, 1907L, 1908L, 1913L, 
1914L, 1929L, 1931L, 1935L, 1954L, 1955L, 1966L, 1971L, 1999L, 
2002L, 2014L, 2024L, 2040L, 2041L, 2042L, 2043L, 2045L, 2054L, 
2074L, 2082L, 2119L, 2126L, 2128L, 2130L, 2131L, 2132L, 2135L, 
2136L, 2137L, 2138L, 2139L, 2140L, 2143L, 2144L, 2158L, 2159L, 
2173L, 2174L, 2175L, 2176L, 2177L, 2180L, 2181L, 2182L, 2183L, 
2193L, 2196L, 2197L, 2217L, 2218L, 2220L, 2222L, 2223L, 2228L, 
2233L, 2236L, 2237L, 2243L, 2244L, 2245L, 2246L, 2255L, 2256L, 
2257L, 2258L, 2261L, 2272L, 2273L, 2274L, 2277L, 2280L, 2303L, 
2304L, 2321L, 2322L, 2327L, 2331L, 2334L, 2335L, 2336L, 2337L, 
2347L, 2348L, 2349L, 2350L, 2354L, 2355L, 2381L, 2382L, 2383L, 
2391L, 2398L, 2403L, 2404L, 2412L, 2413L, 2425L, 2437L, 2442L, 
2466L, 2467L, 2468L, 2469L, 2470L, 2471L, 2472L, 2482L, 2497L, 
2514L, 2524L, 2528L, 2529L, 2530L, 2539L, 2540L, 2541L, 2542L, 
2546L, 2554L, 2569L, 2573L, 2574L, 2576L, 2582L, 2583L, 2584L, 
2588L, 2589L, 2592L, 2595L, 2600L, 2613L, 2614L, 2619L, 2620L, 
2622L, 2630L, 2631L, 2633L, 2637L, 2642L, 2649L, 2650L, 2651L, 
2654L, 2659L, 2666L, 2667L, 2673L, 2685L, 2689L, 2692L, 2699L, 
2713L, 2719L, 2723L, 2729L, 2730L, 2733L, 2746L, 2747L, 2748L, 
2751L, 2757L, 2760L, 2761L, 2762L, 2766L, 2769L, 2770L, 2771L, 
2776L, 2781L, 2791L, 2792L, 2807L, 2808L, 2809L, 2810L, 2811L, 
2813L, 2818L, 2819L, 2822L, 2823L, 2824L, 2826L, 2840L, 2847L, 
2848L, 2850L, 2858L, 2867L, 2871L, 2881L, 2882L, 2885L, 2888L, 
2890L, 2891L, 2892L, 2893L, 2894L, 2903L, 2904L, 2906L, 2907L, 
2908L, 2909L, 2910L, 2912L, 2915L), class = "data.frame")
```